# Kernels of induced maps in cohomology

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, proof-verification, homology-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ and $B$ be two commutative $k$-algebras.  Suppose $\varphi,\psi:A\to B$ are maps of $k$-algebras such that there are algebra automorphisms $G:A\to A$ and $F:B\to B$ with

$$\psi=F\circ \varphi\qquad\varphi=\psi\circ G$$

I'd like to show that under these circumstances, the induced maps in cohomology $\varphi^*,\psi^*:H^*(B,k)\to H^*(A,k)$ have equal kernels.  Suppose $\alpha\in\ker\psi^*$ so that

$$0=G^*\circ\psi^*\circ F^*(\alpha)$$

By invertibility of $G^*$, it follows that $F^*(\alpha)\in\ker\psi^*$ so that $F^*$ stabilizes $\ker\psi^*$.  Find $\beta\in\ker\psi^*$ such that $F^*(\beta)=\alpha$.  Then

$$\varphi^*(\alpha)=\varphi^*\circ F^*(\beta)=\psi^*(\beta)=0$$

so that $\ker\psi^*\subset\ker\varphi^*$.  Reverse the roles of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ to obtain equality.

Two questions:

> 1. Is this proof correct?  If not, is the result still true?
> 2. Is there a result in category theory generalizing this fact?  It seems I haven't used anything specific to the category of $k$-algebras and the contravariant functor $H^*(-,k)$.

Comment: What cohomology theory is this? Also, this should jut ben general homological algebra, there shouldn't be anything in particular about the particular cohomology theory you're using.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: As you have said, the particulars of the cohomology theory don't seem too relevant.  This really seems like it should generalize.  However, for completeness, what I mean by $H^*(A,k)$ is $\mathrm{Ext}_A^*(k,k)$.